# Update Tool from glassfish 3 doesn't start

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

When I start update tool, nothing happens. I tried to do it from command line and from NetBeans. Nothing happens, no errors or exceptions. My OS is Windows 7 64.

Comment: No, I'm not using proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I had (and still have) the same problem using both the Java EE6 and EE7 JDKs.
My solution was to use the Update Tool option in the Domain Admin Console (can be started from within Netbeans or from a browser using localhost:4848).
This solved the problem, but it still annoys me that none of the two options you mention is working.